# RegEx - allow whitespace at end of the string

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have this patterns:

```
^\s*(?=\d*(-\d*){0,2}$)(?=(\d-*){13}$).*$
```

allows strings like "114-4316191466" or "1144316191466" " 1144316191466".
I'd like to allow whitespace also at the end. Best way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is :). `$` is the anchor that matches the end of the string and `\s` is matching a whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

a whitespace is \s so to allow one or more whitespaces add \s+ or \s* at the end (as you did for the beginning of the string)